# Issue with wording of Bounty Notification: The bounty on your question "xyz" expires in the next day

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications

I've got a bounty that's about to expire, and SO told me that I had 3 days left on Monday.

Now, it tells me that: "The bounty on your question "xyz" expires in the next day."

This makes no sense grammatically. It should read

`The bounty on your question "xyz" expires tomorrow.`

Comment: -1 because you're wrong, you can start counting a day from any time, not just midnight; it's just as valid as saying "in the next year" in May.  +1 because there's definitely room to modify the message to include more useful information.

Comment: it makes perfect sense grammatically, but i'd agree that the other wording sounds better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, to fix this *critically important and potentially life threatening bug*, I changed it to "in the next 24 hours".

Comment: You get a salute from me for saving lives!

Answer (score 1):

Actually *in the next 24 hours* / *next day* does sound right.

Comment: "within the next 24 hours" is the only version that I find correct enough.

Answer (score 1):

I second Josh's suggestion and maybe add that giving number of days and hours left might be better.

e.g. The bounty on your question expires in 1 day and 23 hours and definitely give number of hours left if it's <1 day, plus the meaning of tomorrow depends on the timezone.

Comment: Dynamic time on a notification? Perish the thought </s>

Comment: actually - I'm curious - why is it so tough?

Comment: It's not that hard to have a countdown timer, if the actual process of ending a bounty time is set as a specific date, as opposed to a batch process which could be run every 15 minutes, or 2 hours. Given a set time of ending, it isn't too hard to get a countdown timer going, but if there is any more work involved than changing text, Mr Atwood will close it stating 'status-bydesign' ;)